# How to stop video from playing when switch tabbar view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, avplayer

I'm taking an Instagram clone tutorial. I have issues when playing video in table view controller and switching out of that tab bar controller into another view the video is still playing from the previous controller. When researching for possible answers. Most recommend to stop the video player from playing in `viewwillDisappear`. I don't see how this is possible. How do you access the custom cell properties in the view controller outside of `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: Does the video automatically played on scrolling or user tapped on play button?

Comment: It automatically plays when scrolling

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let visiblePaths = self.videoCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems
    for i in visiblePaths  {
        let cell = videoCollectionView.cellForItem(at: i) as? VideoCollectionViewCell
        cell?.pause()
        
    }
```

}